# Guardar valores de Formulario en LocalStorage / JSON - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, formularios, local-storage

Estoy tratando de guardar los valores de un formulario en el LocalStorage para luego pasarlo a JSON, todo en JavaScript, agradezco una ayuda con esto, este es el código que tengo.

CODIGO:

```
var theForm = document.querySelector("#form"),
    valores = []; 

[].forEach.call(theForm.elements, 

    function(elemento){ 
    valores.push(elemento.value); 
});

localStorage.form = JSON.stringify({
    elementos: theForm.innerHTML,
    id: theForm.id || "form", 
    method: theForm.method || "GET", 
    action: theForm.action || "", 
    enctype: theForm.enctype || "", 
    datos: valores 
});
```

Comment: Que problema es el que presentas??? Explica mejor que es lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: En principio el código pareciera que está correcto, hay algún error?

Comment: Vale, estoy tratando de guardar los valores de un formulario con (inputs) a LocalStorage y luego esos datos pasarlos a un JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo este ejemplo que hice para tu problema.

```
//obtener tu form desde el HTML
var form = document.getElementById('tuForm').elements;
for(var i = 0; i<= form.length - 1; i++){
    //aquí puedes agregar mas validaciones que ocupes
    //para efectos de prueba, yo solo permite que se obtuvieran los input de text.
    if(form[i].type == 'text'){
        //imprimir en consola el valor
        console.log(form[i].value);
        //la key sera el ID de tu elemento y despues se asigna el valor
        localStorage.setItem(form[i].id, JSON.stringify(form[i].value));
    }
}
//para probar que se guardaron bien los elementos, probamos en consola.
console.log(localStorage);
```

Recuerda que cada que guardes tu formulario o acciones el `submit`, debes limpiar el localStorage, si no lo haces podría sobreescritura de datos, o perdida, etc.

Espero te funcione, saludos.

Comment: Hola Brandon! Muchas gracias, voy a probarlo y voy a ver que tal!

Comment: Una consuta, me sale en desorden el JSON, como puedo ordenar el orden del mismo? es decir tengo un formulario que tiene los siguientes inputs por ejemplo: Nombre, Apellido, Edad, Fecha, Direccion. Necesito ese orden pero cuando lo paso a JSON me sale asi: Edad, Apellido, Fecha, Direccion, Nombre (Por ejemplo). Como puedo arreglar esto?

Comment: Intentaré ver una posible solución, pero eso ya sería otra pregunta. Marca como correcta esta sí te funciono mi respuesta para el objetivo de esta pregunta; realiza otra deja el link aquí en los comentarios y con gusto responderemos en la nueva pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Que tal Brandon! mira te dejo el link de la pregunta aca: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197267/guardar-json-como-archivo-para-descargalo-en-txt-javascript te agradezco mucho!