# Guardar JSON como archivo para descargalo en .txt - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

Tengo este código para primero reflejar un formulario en LocalStorage y luego pasarlo a JSON, pero necesito descargar un archivo con ciertos datos a un archivo de tipo texto.

Dejo el ejemplo:

```
 function getAllForm(){


    var formID = document.getElementById('form').elements;
    for(var i = 0; i<= formID.length - 1; i++){

        if(formID[i].id == 'nc_' + pCO || 'tc_' + pCO || 'op_' + pCO || 'obl_' + pCO){

            console.log(form[i].value);
            localStorage.setItem(form[i].id, JSON.stringify(form[i].value));
        }

        var jsonOnText = JSON.stringify(form[i].value);
        var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
        hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(jsonOnText);
        hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
        hiddenElement.download = 'jsonOnText.txt';
        hiddenElement.click();

        //return jsonFields; 
    }


    //IMPRIMO EL RESULTADO DEL LOCALSTORAGE EN JSON EN CONSOLA PARA VER
    console.log(localStorage); 
}
```

Agradezo la ayuda, como dije necesito descargar ciertos datos a un archivo de tipo texto.

*Ya lo hago, se decarga PERO solo me trae el primer dato o valor del formulario, ejemplo el formulario tiene: name, lastname, address, email, age) solo me trae el valor de name en este caso, necesito que me guarde todos o solo name, lastname y address.

GRACIAS!